# The existence of a sequence in a non reflexive Banach space

Tags: banach-spaces, duality-theorems, reflexive-space

Let $X$ be a Banach space, and $x\in X$. Is it true that there exists $(x^*_n)$ a sequence in $X^*$ such that $\|x^*_n\| \leq 1$ and $x^*_n(x)\xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{}\|x\|$?
It's true if $X$ is reflexive, but I wonder if it's true otherwise.

Comment: There is something I dimly recall, involving a mathematician called James, who discovered all sorts of weird counterexamples for irreflexive spaces. I believe this was one of them. Eg the “James space” is a famous counterexample. Hopefully you can find something in his work

Comment: As a consequence of the Hahn-Banach theorem, for any normed space $X$ and $x \in X$ there exists $f \in X^*$ such that $\|f\| = 1$ and $f(x) = \|x\|$. So you can just take the constant sequence $(f)_n$.

Comment: you're right, thank you!